# Passing ID with FormHelper

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to create a Form and pass the id in the action, using form helper. 
I want like this:
`<form action="menus/recusar/2>`

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Menus', array('action' => 'recusar', $id)) ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Submit') ?>
```

And the result:

`<form action="/societario/menuses/recusar" 2="2" id="MenusRecusarForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work. Try

```
$id = 2; //Your ID

echo $this->Form->create(null, array(
    'url' => 'menus/recusar/' . $id,
    'type' => 'post'
));

// or

echo $this->Form->create(null, array(
    'url' => array('controller' => 'menus', 'action' => 'recusar', $id)
));
```

Source: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options-for-create

Comment: Hi!! I just eddited the question. `2` must be a variable `$id`. Thnaks

Comment: You can pass the variable instead of constant. check the edit.